# drupal 7 views contextual filter base path

Tags: views

I am using drupal 7 views, I try to use contextual filter, and I noticed that there are 3 base path with a textfield in section "When the filter value is NOT available"

I am confused and not sure what should I key in for that.

Please advise. Below is the screenshot as an example.

I have uploaded the screenshot but not allow to publish due to reputation less than 10
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KsEr.png

Comment: What is being displayed is not correct.  The text and form box should only be displayed once.  The source of the problem is another matter altogether.  It is likely that Views is not the source of the problem. The form is generated by Drupal through the Form API and the display could be affected by other modules.  First, if you fill the form out in one repetition, and save the configuration, are the settings retained when you revisit the form?  Second, if you start in a new view does the same thing occur? Third, if you turn off certain modules does it work?  Fourth, do you have adequate RAM?

Comment: From the above comment, you can see that this is a bug that could come from a variety of sources. Searching is the only option until you get some more clues.